# Remap CapsLock to $?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, remapping, regedit, button-remapping

I have now been trying to remap <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to `$`. But without luck.

I have tried the following binary code.

```
00000000 00000000
02000000 05003A00
00000000
```

When I now press the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> it comes out with a `4` sign, which is the `0500` code in the binary.

I can't seem to find the binary code for `$`.

Does anyone here know the code for `$`? This would really make it faster for me to write PHP, as I never use the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> for that.

Comment: The binary code for $ is `00100100`.  Do you want the hex code?

Comment: Can't you just use something like [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com)?

Comment: @Kruug actually, I think I need the hex yes please.

Comment: @Karan I used SharpKeys to do it, when I type `alt gr + 4` then it comes out with unknown value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 0500 you should put 0005

- 00000000 Header: Version. Set all to zeroes
- 00000000 Flags. Set all to zeroes
- 02000000 Number of entries
- **00053A00** to remove CapsLock, first four digits are for new key, others are for CapsLock.
- 00000000 Null Terminator

Comment: That just doesn't comes out with anything? At all. Any other ides?

Comment: i am sorry try 5000 instead 0005